# How to access Option API's data,computed property and methods in Composition API & vice versa in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

Is there any way to access Option API's data, computed property, methods in Composition API and Composition API's data, computed property and methods in Option API in a same Vue Single File Component(SFC)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Composition API to Option API in Same Component

As @tauzN answered you can return anything from setup in Composition API and use in Options API. See @tauzN's answer for code example

### Option API to Composition API in Same Component

As Vue js official doc suggest,

> Note that the setup() hook of Composition API is called before any Options API hooks, even beforeCreate(). [link](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20the%20setup()%20hook%20of%20Composition%20API%20is%20called%20before%20any%20Options%20API%20hooks%2C%20even%20beforeCreate().)

So we can't access data,computed property or methods from Composition API to Option API.

Answer (score 2):

You can return anything from `setup` in Composition API and use in Options API. [Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup() {
    const compositionRef = ref("Composition")
    return {
      compositionRef
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      optionsRef: "Options"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    inOptionsFromComposition () {
      return this.compositionRef
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ compositionRef }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ optionsRef }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ inOptionsFromComposition }}</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, But how can I access optionsRef inside setup() ? I mean how to access Option API's data in Compotision API ?

Comment: @nur_riyad Not possible :/